Payload validation with tsoa and class-validator in express js
I am using tsoa with class-validator in express js
Now when i define DTO with class-validator and define type for body in tsoa route, it only validates the datataype of the body object values & if it is required or not. It does not validate other properties of class-validator like @IsEmail() or @Length() etc.
Code Example:
// Dto
export class RegisterUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email!: string
}

// Route
@Route('user')
export class UserController extends Controller {
  @Post('/register')
  async createUser(@Body() body: RegisterUserDto) {
    return userService.registerUser(body)
  }
}

// Tsoa generated routes file
const models = {
    "RegisterUserDto": {
        "dataType": "refObject",
        "properties": {
            // Here it should also check if this property is a valid email or not.
            "email": { "dataType": "string", "required": true },
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
    },
}

// Package versions
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "tsoa": "6.2.1",

